# Registering BHO on Windows7

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, com, bho

I have written Browser Helper Object which works fine on computer with windows xp. On machine withwindows 7 something is wrong(when UAC is on). I think tha there is a problem while registering BHO. This is my code used to register BO:

```
        public static string RegistryKeyLocation = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void Register(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (registryKey == null)
        {
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation,);
        }

        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
        RegistryKey bhoKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (bhoKey == null)
        {
            bhoKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
        }

        bhoKey.SetValue("IExplorer Extension", 1);
        registryKey.Close();
        bhoKey.Close();
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction]
    public static void Unregister(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

        if (registryKey != null)
        {
            registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
        }
    }
```

Ho can it be done under windows 7?

I think that is not 'Registring dll' problem. My BHO is registered properly, but not working on non-admin account(when IE is not runed as admin).
maybe something is wrong with events of webbrowser or setsit method is not invoked in protected mode...

```
    public int SetSite(object site)
    {
        if (site != null)
        {
            webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
            webBrowser.OnQuit += new DWebBrowserEvents2_OnQuitEventHandler(webBrowser_OnQuit);

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_ElapsedEvent);
            timer.Interval = 125000;
            timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
            webBrowser.OnQuit -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_OnQuitEventHandler(webBrowser_OnQuit);
            webBrowser = null;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [a question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/15798d6c-2311-4fff-9c9c-ed77f47fbeae) that discusses this same issue. Would it be possible in your situation to use HKCU rather than HKLM?

```
public static string RegistryKeyLocation = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

[ComRegisterFunction]
public static void Register(Type type)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

    if (registryKey == null)
    {
        registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation);
    }

    string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
    RegistryKey bhoKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

    if (bhoKey == null)
    {
        bhoKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
    }

    bhoKey.SetValue("IExplorer Extension", 1);
    registryKey.Close();
    bhoKey.Close();
}

[ComUnregisterFunction]
public static void Unregister(Type type)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
    string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

    if (registryKey != null)
    {
        registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1013552 - Did you look at the answer to the MSDN question? I realize it isn't specifically related to c#, but the answer describes your question none the less. Perhaps you should force your installer to run as `TrustedInstaller` to insure you have the right privileges.

Comment: is it possible that SetSite is not invoked in ProtectedMode? Maybe events are not firing because they are not subscribed...

Comment: @user1013552 - Wouldn't that only matter *after* the BHO is installed?

Comment: I thought that when BHO is installed everything should work properly. But in my case it is not. I have no idea what can be wrong and what can I do with my code to make it work under Win7...

Comment: @user1013552 - [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/6db31651-9fd2-4610-ab8b-a8706aaf817c) msdn thread talks about your issue in depth

Comment: My plugin writes and reads from files which are placed in CommonAppData folder. But from that i have read it may be reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        RegistryKey registryKey =
        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (registryKey == null)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
                                    BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
        RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);

        if (ourKey == null)
        {
            ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        }

        ourKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        registryKey.Close();
        ourKey.Close();


I'm hope this one is good
```